# jQuery Chosen plugin - select option manually

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I've been trying to select some options manually in the Chosen plugin.

**Why i need something like that?**

My concept is :Let's say a user wants to put some tags to a video,when he inserts the video to the database the tags will be saved in a database too. When he wants to edit this video i have to query these tags from the database and show them to the user so he can edit/delete/add new.

**My question:**

Is there any way to put these tags in an array and then put them as an already selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `selected`property when you get the existing tags from the database. Let us say a video is tagged with `a` and `b`, so when you show the `select` list it would look like this:

```
<select id="assets" data-placeholder="Choose assets" class="chzn-select" multiple style="width:350px;">
    <option value="a" selected>a</option>
    <option value="b" selected>b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
    <option value="f">f</option>
    <option value="g">g</option>
</select>
```